# Updating a dictionary using list values as (key , value) pairs results in TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I was trying to update a dictionary using list values as `(key , value)` pairs. But it does not update and throws a TypeError:

```
user_dict = {"bob" : 30, "john": 40}
user_dict.update(["phill", 50])
print(user_dict)
```

> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 5; 2 is required

Comment: If you only need to add a new key value pair to the dictionary, simply you can do it like this `user_dict['phill'] = 50`

Answer (score 0):

You need to represent each key-value pair as an iterable (ex. a tuple `(key1, value1)`), then you need to wrap it in *another* iterable, then that's the one you pass in. Here is the docs on the [`dict.update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) function:

> #### **update**([other])
>
> Update the dictionary with the key/value pairs from *other*, overwriting existing keys. Return `None`.
>
> `update()` accepts either another dictionary object or an iterable of key/value pairs (as tuples or other iterables of length two). If
> keyword arguments are specified, the dictionary is then updated with
> those key/value pairs: `d.update(red=1, blue=2)`.

The key-value pair can be a tuple then you can pass a list of it:

```
In [4]: user_dict = {"bob" : 30, "john": 40}

In [5]: user_dict.update([ ('phill',50) ])

In [6]: user_dict
Out[6]: {'bob': 30, 'john': 40, 'phill': 50}
```

The key-value pair can also be a list then you can pass a list of it:

```
In [12]: user_dict = {"bob" : 30, "john": 40}

In [13]: user_dict.update([ ['phill',50] ])

In [14]: user_dict
Out[14]: {'bob': 30, 'john': 40, 'phill': 50}
```

The key-value can also be a tuple then you can pass a tuple of it (take note that you need to add a trailing of `,` to make a tuple of 1):

```
In [18]: user_dict = {"bob" : 30, "john": 40}

In [19]: user_dict.update(( ('phill',50), ))

In [20]: user_dict
Out[20]: {'bob': 30, 'john': 40, 'phill': 50}
```

To make you life simpler, you can just pass in a mapping (ex. another dict):

```
In [1]: user_dict = {"bob" : 30, "john": 40}

In [2]: user_dict.update( {"phill": 50} )

In [3]: user_dict
Out[3]: {'bob': 30, 'john': 40, 'phill': 50}
```